# Can't choose an option on a configurable product, when i merge javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I have a bit of a problem. I have huge amount of JavaScript on my site, and when i am trying to merge it, i suddenly can't choose an option.

The console in Google Chrome shows this:

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**
The code is simply to long

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OptionsPrice' of undefined**

```
<script>
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice({"productId":"224","priceFormat":{"pattern":"%s\u00a0DKK ","precision":2,"requiredPrecision":2,"decimalSymbol":",","groupSymbol":".","groupLength":3,"integerRequired":1},"includeTax":"true","showIncludeTax":true,"showBothPrices":false,"productPrice":29,"productOldPrice":29,"priceInclTax":29,"priceExclTax":29,"skipCalculate":1,"defaultTax":25,"currentTax":25,"idSuffix":"_clone","oldPlusDisposition":0,"plusDisposition":0,"plusDispositionTax":0,"oldMinusDisposition":0,"minusDisposition":0,"tierPrices":[],"tierPricesInclTax":[]});
</script>
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Config' of undefined**

```
<script>
        var spConfig = new Product.Config({"attributes":{"145":{"id":"145","code":"size","label":"St\u00f8rrelse","options":[{"id":"32","label":"10ml","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["225","226","227","228"]},{"id":"31","label":"30ml","price":"30","oldPrice":"30","products":["229","230","231","232"]}]},"146":{"id":"146","code":"styrke","label":"Styrke","options":[{"id":"36","label":"0mg","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["225","229"]},{"id":"35","label":"6mg","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["226","230"]},{"id":"34","label":"12mg","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["227","231"]},{"id":"33","label":"18mg","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["228","232"]}]}},"template":"#{price}\u00a0DKK ","basePrice":"29","oldPrice":"29","productId":"224","chooseText":"--V\u00e6lg venligst--","taxConfig":{"includeTax":true,"showIncludeTax":true,"showBothPrices":false,"defaultTax":25,"currentTax":25,"inclTaxTitle":"Inkl. moms"}});
    </script>
```

**Uncaught Reference Error: Calendar is not defined**

```
Calendar._DN = ["s\u00f8ndag","mandag","tirsdag","onsdag","torsdag","fredag","l\u00f8rdag"]; // full day names
```

I hope there is someway that you can help me.
I am on a Magento platform, with a custom template.

Thanks

Comment: We are not psychic. Without some code there is no way we can answer this.

Comment: you may have jquery conflict issue.add jQuery.noConflict() at the end of jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a syntax error in one of the JS files. Either in the one where `Product` is defined or where you get your first error.

Sometimes you miss a comma and your entire object is not defined. I would look for that first.

The easiest way is to use JSLint.

Comment: But which JS file.. I am totally lost.

Comment: You are not supplying enough information, until you do, suggestions like mine will be the best we can give. They are educated guesses at best. Sorry that I can't be of more help. Many things can cause errors like yours.

Answer (score 0):

where is "Product" defined?
you should first have Product in your page! or is it defined in a closure function?

Comment: I really dont understand. I have a product in my page, and it works fine until i merge all the javascript.

Comment: jshint your js file! or partially delete your code in the js file to check where the error occured! and what caused it!